# Remotely registry path controlling via powershell

Tags: powershell

My conditions are :

if `NeedReboot` key is exist then result will be `Pending reboot`
if `NeedReboot` key is  not exist then result will be `NO Pending reboot`

My desired output :

```
Computername,Rebootrequired
Host01,Pending reboot
Host02,NO Pending reboot
```

Script :

```
$allComputers = Get-Content '.\path\to\computers.txt'


$domainCred = Get-Credential -UserName "domain01\admin01" -Message "Please enter the DOMAIN password"

$Results = foreach($computer in $allComputers) {

 $cred    = $domainCred


  try {
             
                $VmTools = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
                           Test-Path -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\NeedReboot\"
                       } -ErrorAction Stop
               
                [PsCustomObject]@{ ComputerName = $computer; RebootRequired = ([int]$VmTools -eq "True") }
            }
            
            
}
            
$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize


$Results | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\vmtools.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the final backslash after the registry path.

Then, `Test-Path` just returns $true or $false, so converting that to [int] and comparing to the string `"True"` makes no sense..

Try

```
[PsCustomObject]@{ 
    ComputerName   = $computer
    RebootRequired = if($VmTools) {"Pending Reboot") } else {"NO Pending Reboot"}
}
```

The code is also missing a `catch{..}` block that should accompany the `try {..}` block. Something like:

```
catch {
    [PsCustomObject]@{ 
        ComputerName   = $computer
        RebootRequired = "Error reading registry"
    }
}
```